# Xcode8 - iOS10 - App delegate

Tags: xcode8

I have an old application which I am now running on iOS10 built using the latest Xcode8.
On very first run to the device the application works perfectly, however, when I background the app and re-open it stalls at the splash screen.
Anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: No, & try running it with XCode 8 GM or XCode 8

Comment: I had the same issue and I solve it fixing some auto layout bugs on view than it worked. Seems stupid but worked on my case :)